# How is modularity a weakened form of distributivity?

Tags: lattice-orders, universal-algebra

While reading an essay Lattice Theory- Its Birth and Life, the following line confused me:

> modularity is a weakened form of distributivity

Just to be clear, here modularity and distributivity of lattices is being considered

The essay can be found [here](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/401261)

A similar statement can be found in the book [General Lattice Theory](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=SoGLVCPuOz0C&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=modularity+is+a+weakened+form+of+distributivity&source=bl&ots=5ZH1deO8La&sig=PiVW9QiFkqZmcUtro8w-n95wWaY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EKzeUtWGBYOHrgfVjoHQDA&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=modularity%20is%20a%20weakened%20form%20of%20distributivity&f=false) by George Grätzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributive lattices are modular.  The proof can be found [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+lattice#examples) for example (it's the first example).

Answer (score 0):

Modular lattices forbid [1 {1, [1,1]} 1] and distributive lattices forbid both  [1 {1, [1,1]} 1] and [1 3 1].